# What exactly occurs when the while loop runs (what is done within the while loop)? (It's supposed to remove the substring and the character behind it)

Tags: java, substring, indexof

```
 public String removeStrings()
 {  
    String cleaned = sentence; //sentence and remove are inputs
    int loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);
    while (loc>-1) //need explanation on how this works
    { 
      cleaned = cleaned.substring(0, loc-1)+cleaned.substring(loc+remove.length());
      loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);
    }
    return cleaned;
}
```

Example input sentence="xR-MxR-MHelloxR-M" and remove="R-M" //has to remove x as well in this case
https://github.com/AndrewWeiler/AndrewMac/blob/master/ACSWeiler/src/Lab09/StringRemover.java

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 when it doesn't find `remove` in `cleaned`.

Comment: You may want to read up on how [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) and [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.substring() either returns the part ob a String between two positions (in `cleaned.substring(0, 1)`, that would be the content of `cleaned` between position 0 and 1) or if you give that method just 1 int-argument, it returns the part of your String, that comes after that position.

For example, with `sentence="xR-MxR-MHelloxR-M" and remove="R-M"` you would get:

```
cleaned = "xR-MxR-MHelloxR-M"
loc = 1
```

So the while-loop would go like this:

`cleaned.substring(0, loc-1)` returns `"x"` and `cleaned.substring(loc+remove.length())` returns `"xR-MHelloxR-M"`. So `cleaned = "xxR-MHelloxR-M"`. Then, loc becomes the position of the next occurrence of `remove`.

In words, your while loop removes every occurrence of the String `remove` out of the String `sentence` and saves the result in `cleaned`.

For substring() check https://www.javatpoint.com/substring.

**Edit:**

If you want the first character before your substring to be removed too, you just need to say

```
loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove) - 1;
```